# UILabel flicker when changing font dynamically on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swift

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 90.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //ask for a reusable cell from the tableview, the tableview will create a new one if it doesn't have any
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DetailCell") as DetailCell

    var detail : Detail
    detail = Details[indexPath.row]

    var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 15
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right

    var attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: detail.detailText)
    attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

    var fontName = cell.myLabel.font.fontName

    cell.myLabel.font = UIFont(name:fontName, size: pointSize)
    cell.myLabel.attributedText = attrString


    return cell
}
@IBAction func pinched(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
{
    pointSize = ((sender.velocity > 0) ? 1 : -1) * 0.5 + pointSize;

    if (pointSize < MIN_SIZE)
    {
        pointSize = MIN_SIZE
    }
    else if (pointSize > MAX_SIZE)
    {
        pointSize = MAX_SIZE
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

pointSize changes as the user pinches (used UIPinchRecognizer)
the default pointSize of myLabel is 17.
The code works perfectly when pinched to increase or decrease the pointSize.
But while scrolling first the default size is applied and then increased or decreased size due to this the cells are giving a flicker effect while scrolling.

How do I avoid this?
Is there any sample example already done for UITableViewCells

Comment: You are using the wrong `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier` function. You should be using the one which takes indexPath as an argument. It should help with performance. Not sure about the flicker.

Comment: In that function, the cell should be created with the right size. When you say starts with the default then flickers due to increase/decrease, why is the cell not starting with the right size in the first place?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel - I think you're question is the implicit question in the post.  Please post the technique used to change the size during the pinch.  It ought to culminate with modifying the point size and reloading visible rows.

Comment: @danh edited in the original post

Comment: Does your scroll by any chance trigger your pinched function or your pinch gesture code. Sounds like something is causing updates while you scroll. You do need to change your dequeue method to the proper version as it could be causing you issues. The version you are using has known isues with size classes and layout as cells created have no superview when created. Use the forIndexPath version.

Comment: @Rory McKinnel now using proper dequeue method with forIndexPath still have the same problem. What i think is that when font is changed the cell height changes and because of this there is a flicker.

Comment: What do you return for heightForRowAtIndexPath? Might be good to see more code.

Comment: @Rory McKinnel heightForRowAtIndexPath is not implemented since these properties takes care of the height dynamically

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 90.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: If you disable your gesture code and set the font to be bigger than the cells default font do you see the same effect? Just to rule the gesture code out of things. If so then it sounds like a defect in the auto layout code. There are aquite a few mentions of flicker in other articles. Sadly out of ideas.

Comment: @Rory McKinnel I had actually tried it with no success. As you said seems to be auto layout issue. The only way I could think of to solve this problem is to have different prototype cells for different font size. May be I'll keep only 3 prototypes of different font size pointing to same UITableViewCell class. what do you think of this solution for now?

Comment: Prototype cells probably worth a go. I do that for all my tables as I have to support iOS7 and I have had no issues.